# Dockerfile `RUN --mount=type=ssh` doesn't seem to work

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In my Dockerfile, I'm trying to pull a Python lib from a private repo:

```
RUN --mount=type=ssh .venv/bin/pip install SOME_LIB --extra-index-url https://example.com/pypi/ -U
```

Then I tried to run the build using the following command:

```
docker buildx build --ssh /path/to/the/private/key/id_rsa .
```

For some reason, it gave me the following error:

```
#0 0.831   Host key verification failed.
#0 0.831   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I've double checked the private key is correct. Did I miss any step to use `--mount=type=ssh`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with your private key; it is "host key verification failed". That means that `ssh` doesn't recognize the key being presented by the remote host. It's default behavior is to ask if it should trust the hostkey, and when run in an environment when it can't prompt interactively, it will simply reject the key.

You have a few options to deal with this. In the following examples, I'll be cloning a GitHub private repository (so I'm interacting with github.com), but the process is the same for any other host to which you're connecting with ssh.

- Inject a global `known_hosts` file when you build the image.

  First, get the hostkey for the hosts to which you'll be connecting
  and save it alongside your `Dockerfile`:

  ```
  $ ssh-keyscan github.com > known_hosts
  ```

  Configure your `Dockerfile` to install this where `ssh` will find
  it:

  ```
  COPY known_hosts /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
  RUN chmod 600 /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts; \
    chown root:root /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
  ```
- Configure ssh to trust unknown host keys:

  ```
  RUN sed /^StrictHostKeyChecking/d /etc/ssh/ssh_config; \
    echo StrictHostKeyChecking no >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config
  ```
- Run `ssh-keyscan` in your `Dockerfile` when building the image:

  ```
  RUN ssh-keyscan github.com > /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
  ```

All three of these solutions will ensure that ssh trusts the remote host key. The first option is the most secure (the known hosts file will only be updated by you explicitly when you run `ssh-keyscan` locally).  The last option is probably the most convenient.

Comment: Great answer. . . a lot of answers on this may fail because they lack the  `StrictHostKeyChecking` that you covered.